# JSF 2.2 HTML5 Pass-through attributes

Tags: html, jsf-2

I am trying to use JSF 2.2 innovations html5 pass-through attributes feature.

Name-spaced attribute on the component tag working with m09 version.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0-m09</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough">
  <h:head>
    <title>HTML 5</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:inputText p:placeholder="Enter text"/>    
  </h:body>
</html>
```

But do not work with newer versions.

The f:passThroughAttributes tag is working with newer versions.

Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the following namespace :

```
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

Explanation:

> The new namespace xmlns.jcp.org must be used for the new passthrough stuff for 2.2 (since this is new for 2.2).
>   You can use the old (java.sun.com) or new (xmlns.jcp.org) namespace for the ui, h and f namespaces since we need to preserve compatibility. But I would encourage you to use the new namespace for everything going forward for 2.2.

Here is the JIRA reference : [Passthrough attributes not working when used with prefixing the attribute with the shortname assigned to the http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2796?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)

Comment: Thank you daniel. Is IDE's(example netbeans intelij) does not support automatic code completion?

Comment: You are welcome, They all does , take a look at this : https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-support.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058175/how-to-reactivate-code-assist-in-my-xhtml-page-eclipse-3-5-jboss-tools-3-1-js

Comment: This should be `xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"` according to https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/p/tld-summary.html