# Custom attribute in myfaces JSF2.2

Tags: jsf-2.2, myfaces

I want to add custom attribute to existing UI components in myFaces JSF2.2 .All the examples in internet talks about using com.sun.faces.renderkit .I will not be able to use this as my application runs on websphere liberty and will be having only MyFaces .Is there any way I can achieve this with MyFaces.
This is required for adding accessbility related attributes

Comment: if this is about the `aria-*` attributes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984941/jsf-datatable-not-complying-to-wcag-due-to-unsupported-aria-label-attribute

Comment: oh and if you really do want to extend all components (don't go there) the myfaces IMPLEMENTATION also has renderkit counterparts. Easy to find in the source...

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546135/putting-a-role-in-facelets-composition-shows-message-attribute-role-is-not-al

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSF datatable not complying to WCAG due to unsupported aria-label attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984941/jsf-datatable-not-complying-to-wcag-due-to-unsupported-aria-label-attribute)

Comment: oh yes thanks I jsut checked the passthrough feature of JSF2.2 and it looks promising let me dig and try

Comment: Please also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189372/javaserver-faces-2-2-and-html5-support-why-is-xhtml-still-being-used). Note the possible usage of the http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf namespace to decorate your "native html5" components with jsf tags.